# Calculus Practice Question

Tags: calculus

Determine the equation of the line that is formed by joining the points where the function is $g(x)= \ln(x)^3+2(\ln x)^2$ has horizontal tangent lines.

So far I derived $g(x)$ and set it equal to zero. I solved for $x$ and found two values. What do I do next?

Thanks.

Comment: Well, if you know the $x$ values where $g$ has a horizontal tangent line, then you presumably know the $f(x)$ values that correspond to those $x$-values. In particular, you should have two points $(x_{1},f(x_{1}))$ and $(x_{2},f(x_{2}))$. Do you know how to find the equation of a line given two points?

Comment: To be clear, you used both $\ln(x)^3$ and $(\ln x)^2$ in the same line.  Do you mean for the first to be $\ln(x^3)$ or do you mean for the first to also be $(\ln x)^3$?  Although you didn't use it, you should also be careful of $\ln^3(x)$ which some might interpret as functional composition $\ln(\ln(\ln(x)))$ rather than $(\ln(x))^3$